# mariadb char(250)*20 vs text(5000) for perfomance

Tags: mariadb

I have about 100 million texts(text length 4500~5000). I'm going to put them in mariadb, and the query I use is as follows.

```
SELECT TT_TEXT FROM TEXT_TABLE WHERE TT_HASH = UNHEX('MD5 HASH');
```

Which perfomance would be better for TEXT_TABLE1 or TEXT_TABLE2? The capacity of the database doesn't matter. Just the select perfomance.

```
# TABLE1
CREATE TABLE `TEXT_TABLE1` (
    `TT_INDEX` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Index',
    `TT_HASH` BINARY(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'MD5 hash for `TT_TEXT`',
    `TT_TEXT` TEXT(5000) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Text for 4500~5000 length',
PRIMARY KEY (`TT_INDEX`),
UNIQUE KEY (`TT_HASH`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT 'Text table';
```

vs

```
# TABLE2
CREATE TABLE `TEXT_TABLE2` (
    `TT_INDEX` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Index',
    `TT_HASH` BINARY(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'MD5 hash for `TT_TEXT`',
    `TT_TEXT1` CHAR(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Text for 4500~5000 length',
    ...
    `TT_TEXT20` CHAR(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Text for 4500~5000 length',
PRIMARY KEY (`TT_INDEX`),
UNIQUE KEY (`TT_HASH`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT 'Text table';
```

Comment: Your second table design would make it almost impossible to use. Stop worrying about premature optimization and just use proper table design principles.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.